# set org-mode as a source-language in an org-mode document

Tags: org-mode, org-export, markdown

I want to export an org-mode document to markdown.  My document contains some content like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC
* User-defined Markers
** MARKER_1
#+END_SRC
```

I would like to demonstrate how someone could write something in an org-mode document, but when this is exported to markdown, it is interpreted as org-mode text, i.e. instead of seeing a gray code field, the export tries to structure the markdown using 'User-defined Markers' as a headline.  Is there any way of exporting so that what's inside of #BEGIN_SRC is not evaluated?

Comment: Should source blocks open an escape route from the stars ?

Comment: If you add the language header argument like `#+BEGIN_SRC org` you even get nice highlighting of the org source code when you export to HTML.

Comment: @Tobias Thanks for the tip about syntax highlighting, but the org-mode code inside the source blocks was still being evaluated when I exported.  NickD's suggestion worked.

Comment: Using `#+BEGIN_SRC org` was not a solution to your question but a comment what you could do additional to NickD's solution.

Comment: @tobias alles klar :)

Comment: @DavidJ. if you use `#+BEGIN_SRC org` and then edit that block as usual with C-c C-c the , is added for you if needed and the export works as it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any lines that could be confused as Org mode markup (e.g. both of the lines in your example block) can be quoted by preceding them with a `,`:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC
,* User-defined Markers
,** MARKER_1
#+END_SRC
```

See [Literal Examples](https://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-Examples.html#Literal-Examples) in the manual.

As @Tobias and @Hubisan point out in the comments, it's a very good idea to mark the source block as an org source block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC org
,* User-defined Markers
,** MARKER_1
#+END_SRC
```

There are several advantages:

- You get nice highlighting when exporting to HTML (and possibly other formats).
- `C-c '` (bound to `org-edit-special`) knows to edit the contents of the source block using the `org-mode` major mode. It also knows to strip the commas when entering and adding them back when exiting, so you don't have to worry about them any more.